# Unable to use aws-encryption-cli after successfull installation

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, devops

After installing aws-encryption-sdk-cli as mentioned in the official documentation provided by amazon. I am not able to check the version or encrypt/decrypt any file using aws-encryption-cli. While checking version installed its giving following error.

> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aws_encryption_sdk/caches/**init**.py:21: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in the next release.
> from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

can anyone help please?

Comment: Consider raising an issue at https://github.com/aws/aws-encryption-sdk-cli/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through various blogs, I came to know it's version dependency issue  of cryptography package for `aws-encryption-cli`. First install the specific version of `cryptography(3.4.7)`, then install `aws-encryption-cli` again. To install the specific version of cryptography package, you can use the below command.

`pip install cryptography==3.4.7`